# How to call a generic function with a dynamic type in Swift

Tags: swift, generics

Say I have a protocol `Fooable`:

```
protocol Fooable {}
```

Now I need to work with a `Fooable` type in a generic function:

```
func fooingAround<FooableType: Fooable>(withType: FooableType.Type) {}
```

This works fine when I just call the function with a `Fooable` type:

```
struct Foo: Fooable {}
fooingAround(Foo.self) // works fine
```

However, I need to retrieve the `Fooable` type that I hand over to the function from somewhere else. This is where the compiler fails:

```
let fooableType: Fooable.Type = // obtain from somewhere else
fooingAround(fooableType) // compiler error: "Cannot invoke 'fooingAround' with an argument list of type '(Fooable.Type)'"
```

Specifically, I obtain the `Fooable.Type` from an enum that describes API endpoints, where each endpoint is represented by a different `Fooable` class.

I suppose the problem arises because I *dynamically* obtain a type, so there can be no strong typing at compile time.

Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this:

```
let fooableType: Fooable.Type = // obtain from somewhere else
```

... is casting into oblivion precisely the information you want to store in that variable, i.e. what is the concrete type that is conforming to `Fooable`. Consider that the following code compiles:

```
protocol Fooable {}

func fooingAround<FooableType: Fooable>(withType: FooableType.Type) {}

struct Foo: Fooable {}
fooingAround(Foo) // works fine

let foo = Foo()
let fooableType /* do not cast here */ = foo.dynamicType

fooingAround(fooableType) // also works fine
```

... which means that you have to find a way to directly pipe the type information into your function call without casting.

Depending on the sort of `fooingAround` you have in mind, you may for example be able to extend `Fooable` along the following lines:

```
extension Fooable {

    func fooingAround() {
        /* do some fooing with */ self.dynamicType // which is the Foo.Type when called on the `foo` value
    }
}

foo.fooingAround()
```